# Como fazer um scroll com setas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rolamento, touch

estou trabalhando em um projeto para aplicativo em monitor touch screen, e preciso fazer o esquema conforme a imagem a seguir.

[image: SCROLL COM SETAS]

Será um lista de itens, dentro de uma div por exemplo, e terá que ser um scroll com botões conforme a imagem, onde estão as setas, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer.

Comment: É o mesmo princípio. Talvez lhe ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/270716/99718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o `animate` do jQuery com `scrollTop`, controlando o *scroll* da `div` para cima ou para baixo.

Segue um exemplo prático que você pode customizar como quiser:

```js
$("#botoes li").on("click", function(){
   var index = $(this).index();
   var lista_top = $("#lista").scrollTop();
   
   // o valor "20" é quanto em pixels irá rolar
   // 150 é o tempo da animação. Quanto maior, mais lenta.
   $("#lista").animate({ scrollTop: lista_top+Number((index == 0 && '-')+20) }, 150);
});
```

```css
*{
   position: relative;
}

ul, li{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
}

#botoes{
   display: inline-block;
   position: fixed;
   top: 10px;
   right: 10px;
   z-index: 9;
}

#botoes li{
   display: block;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: #fff;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin: 1px;
   text-align: center;
}

#botoes li:hover{
   background-color: #ddd;
}

#botoes li:active{
   background-color: #090;
}

#botoes li i{
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  top: 5px;
}

.seta_cima{
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);  
   transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.seta_baixo{
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);  
   transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#lista{
   display: block;
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   padding: 15px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista">
   <h3>Texto</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce a massa et justo ornare porta. Vestibulum non vestibulum diam. Cras sagittis vitae orci in ultrices. Curabitur vulputate, ex sed placerat porta, diam lacus elementum felis, nec iaculis leo nulla et dolor. Proin aliquet, urna sed sodales condimentum, orci quam finibus ex, vitae sagittis metus nisi commodo mauris. In quis leo sodales, auctor nisl ac, rutrum felis. In sed est sollicitudin neque egestas volutpat facilisis ac metus.</p>
   <p>Praesent fringilla blandit velit vel auctor. Proin porta commodo erat a gravida. Nulla id ultrices massa. Quisque eu dui auctor, faucibus lacus vel, tempus diam. Sed sed ultrices massa. Suspendisse pellentesque, est non varius imperdiet, ex neque gravida magna, non vestibulum diam leo sed ligula. Aliquam id quam sed elit sollicitudin consequat id eu ex. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam rutrum egestas leo id molestie. Mauris volutpat nulla vel interdum fermentum. Pellentesque magna sapien, sollicitudin sed fringilla ut, tincidunt sed massa. Vivamus urna tellus, varius non consequat vel, elementum ut libero.</p>
</div>
<div id="botoes">
   <ul>
      <li><i class="seta_cima"></i></li>
      <li><i class="seta_baixo"></i></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```