# Descer "Scrollar" Página Devagar e Automático com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animate

Tenho uma página que mostra algumas informações em um monitor que não vai ter intervenção humana (não vai ter usuário manipulando a página), ficará em exibição apenas. Mas o conteúdo que é muito grande e preciso que a página desça sozinha para mostrar todo o conteúdo. Já tentei usar o animate do JQuery, mas não obtive sucesso.

Segue meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html style="position: relative; min-height: 100%;">
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="~/Content/Imagens/logo_araguaina.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/CSS/painel-chegada-partida.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/mostra-data-hora.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()" style="overflow-x: hidden">
<div>@RenderBody()</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 ml-md-3">
    <img src="~/Content/Imagens/Logo-Prefeitura-De-Araguaina (1).png" style="height: 70px;" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 d-md-flex justify-content-md-center mt-md-2">
    <h2 style="font-size: 37px;" class="font-weight-bold">PARTIDAS</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 ml-md-5 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
    <img src="~/Content/Imagens/Logo ASTT e Acesso.png" style="height: 70px;" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-active" style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
    <thead style="background-color:black; color: white; font-size: 22px;">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 110px;">LINHA</th>
            <th style="width: 150px;">EMPRESA</th>
            <th style="width: 260px;">ORIGEM</th>
            <th style="width: 300px;">DESTINO</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; width: 100px;">PARTIDA</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; width: 120px;">CHEGADA</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; width: 60px;">BOX</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">OBSERVAÇÃO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 18px;">
        @foreach (var partidas in ViewBag.Partidas)`
        {
            if (partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem == "PARTIDAS DO DIA")
            {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            else
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@partidas.Cd_Cod_Linha</td>
                    @*<td style="text-align: left;">@chegadas.Ds_Empresa</td>*@
                    @if (partidas.Ds_Caminho_Logo == "")
                    {
                        <td style="text-align: left;">@partidas.Ds_Empresa</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td style="text-align: left;"><img height="35" src="~/Content/Imagens/@partidas.Ds_Caminho_Logo" /></td>

                        @*<td style="text-align: left;"><img height="35" src="/Imagens/logoACESSO.png" /></td>*@
                    }
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;">@partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;">@partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">@partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">@*@partidas.Hr_Chegada_Local*@</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">@partidas.Ds_Plataforma</td>
                    <td style="color: red;"><marquee>@partidas.Ds_Observacao</marquee></td>
                    @*<td><div class="marquee"><span>@partidas.Ds_Observacao</span></div></td>*@
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<footer style="background-color: black; bottom: 0;" class="col-md-12 position-absolute">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 d-md-flex justify-content-md-center w-25">
        <!--inicio Widget previsão do tempo Araguaina CPTEC/INPE -->
        <iframe allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/widget.php?p=558&w=n&c=000000&f=ffffff" height="45" width="260"></iframe><noscript>Previs&atilde;o de <a href="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/cidades/tempo/558">Araguaína/TO</a> oferecido por <a href="http://www.cptec.inpe.br">CPTEC/INPE</a></noscript>
        <!--fim Widget previsão do tempo Araguaina CPTEC/INPE -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-md-flex justify-content-md-center font-weight-bold" style="margin-top: -10px;">
        <span class="mostra-hora"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-md-flex justify-content-md-center w-25">
        <!--inicio Widget previsão do tempo Palmas CPTEC/INPE -->
        <iframe allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/widget.php?p=236&w=n&c=000000&f=ffffff" height="45" width="260"></iframe><noscript>Previs&atilde;o de <a href="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/cidades/tempo/236">Palmas/TO</a> oferecido por <a href="http://www.cptec.inpe.br">CPTEC/INPE</a></noscript>
        <!--fim Widget previsão do tempo Palmas CPTEC/INPE -->
    </div>
</div>
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">


var url = "@Url.Action("MostraAviso", "Mensagem")";

window.onload = function abreChegadas() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = url;
    }, 15000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A página toda??

Comment: Você pode fazer dessa forma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/270716/99718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o **[animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** mesmo para fazer o efeito.

Fiz abaixo um exemplo em que a animação se baseia na altura do `body` e da altura da janela para calcular a velocidade (veja comentários no código). Basta adicionar o script na pagina que a animação se inicia:

**Script:**

```
<script>
$(function(){
   (function inicia(){
      var altura_pagina = $("body").outerHeight(true);
      var altura_janela = window.innerHeight;
      var velocidade = 5000; // quanto maior, mais lento
      var intervalo = 3 // intervalo em segundos para reinicar

      $(this).scrollTop(0);

      $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: altura_pagina-altura_janela
      }, (altura_pagina/500) * velocidade, "linear", function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
            inicia();
         }, intervalo*1000);
      });
   }());
});
</script>
```

**Exemplo baseado no seu código:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html style="position: relative; min-height: 100%;">
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="~/Content/Imagens/logo_araguaina.ico" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
   (function inicia(){
      var altura_pagina = $("body").outerHeight(true);
      var altura_janela = window.innerHeight;
      var velocidade = 5000; // quanto maior, mais lento
      var intervalo = 3 // intervalo em segundos para reinicar

      $(this).scrollTop(0);

      $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: altura_pagina-altura_janela
      }, (altura_pagina/500) * velocidade, "linear", function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
            inicia();
         }, intervalo*1000);
      });
   }());
});
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/CSS/painel-chegada-partida.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/mostra-data-hora.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="overflow-x: hidden">
<div>@RenderBody()</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 ml-md-3">
    <img src="~/Content/Imagens/Logo-Prefeitura-De-Araguaina (1).png" style="height: 70px;" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 d-md-flex justify-content-md-center mt-md-2">
    <h2 style="font-size: 37px;" class="font-weight-bold">PARTIDAS</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 ml-md-5 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
    <img src="~/Content/Imagens/Logo ASTT e Acesso.png" style="height: 70px;" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-active" style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
    <thead style="background-color:black; color: white; font-size: 22px;">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 110px;">LINHA</th>
            <th style="width: 150px;">EMPRESA</th>
            <th style="width: 260px;">ORIGEM</th>
            <th style="width: 300px;">DESTINO</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; width: 100px;">PARTIDA</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; width: 120px;">CHEGADA</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; width: 60px;">BOX</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">OBSERVAÇÃO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 18px;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="linha-data-seguinte" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(245, 184, 52, 0.63);">
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                        @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Origem @partidas.Ds_Cidade_Destino @partidas.Hr_Previsao_Saida
                        <img class="imagem-seta" src="~/Content/Imagens/seta-para-baixo_318-1470.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

</div>

<footer style="background-color: black; bottom: 0;" class="col-md-12 position-absolute">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 d-md-flex justify-content-md-center w-25">
        <!--inicio Widget previsão do tempo Araguaina CPTEC/INPE -->
        <iframe allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/widget.php?p=558&w=n&c=000000&f=ffffff" height="45" width="260"></iframe><noscript>Previs&atilde;o de <a href="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/cidades/tempo/558">Araguaína/TO</a> oferecido por <a href="http://www.cptec.inpe.br">CPTEC/INPE</a></noscript>
        <!--fim Widget previsão do tempo Araguaina CPTEC/INPE -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-md-flex justify-content-md-center font-weight-bold" style="margin-top: -10px;">
        <span class="mostra-hora"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-md-flex justify-content-md-center w-25">
        <!--inicio Widget previsão do tempo Palmas CPTEC/INPE -->
        <iframe allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/widget.php?p=236&w=n&c=000000&f=ffffff" height="45" width="260"></iframe><noscript>Previs&atilde;o de <a href="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/cidades/tempo/236">Palmas/TO</a> oferecido por <a href="http://www.cptec.inpe.br">CPTEC/INPE</a></noscript>
        <!--fim Widget previsão do tempo Palmas CPTEC/INPE -->
    </div>
</div>
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">



//var url = "@Url.Action('MostraAviso', 'Mensagem')";
//
//window.onload = function abreChegadas() {
//    window.setTimeout(function () {
//        window.location.href = url;
//    }, 150000);
//}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: É isso mesmo! Funcionou perfeitamente. Só mais uma dúvida, como faço para que no término do Scroll ele redirecione para outra página ao invés de reiniciar o animate?

Comment: Que espere alguns segundos.

Comment: Onde tem "inicia()" dentro do setTimeout, vc troca por location.href = "pagina.html";

Comment: Tentei fazer isso, mas aí ele não inicia o animate quando carrega a página

Comment: Já tem, eu uso MVC. Coloquei o código de animação no arquivo de cabeçalho do site, todas as páginas usam esse cabeçalho.

Comment: Em nenhuma página iniciou a animação?

Comment: Não. Ele redireciona no intervalo que eu determinei, mas não faz a animação.

Comment: Quer que eu faça outra pergunta?

Comment: Quando eu coloco o location.href ele não faz o animate em nenhuma página, apenas redireciona para a outra página que também não faz a animação

Comment: Encontrei o problema. Eram os dois `()` no final do script. Dá uma olhada na resposta que atualizei.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt90z.png

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Agora funcionou tanto o animate quanto o location.href. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @DiegoGrossi Só mais uma coisa, pode apagar isso tb `$(this).stop();`.

Comment: Muito obrigado novamente!